# Issue in creating custom category attribute Magento2

Tags: magento2, category-attribute

I am creating custom attribute of type select, its creating but not picking values from defined source, instead its showing 'yes/no' option to select .

Here is mine code in Setup/InstallData.php

```
   namespace Mymodule\CatAttributeSet\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0') < 0){



        $eavSetup -> removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'cat_attribute_set');


            $eavSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category :: ENTITY, 'cat_attribute_set', [
                        'type' => 'int',
                        'label' => 'Associated Attribute set',
                        'input' => 'select',
                        'source' => 'Mymodule\CatAttributeSet\Model\Config\Source\AttributesetOptions',
                        'required' => true,
                        'sort_order' => 110,
                        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'group' => 'General Information',
                        "note"       => "It is using on frontend while seller creating products."
            ]
            );

        }

    }
}
```

While I am trying to debug and apply the print statement in defined source model than its printing my source model values but in admin category detail page its giving option "Yes/No" in my custom attribute to select.

Here is my source model file's code -

```
    namespace Mymodule\CatAttributeSet\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\OptionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;


class AttributesetOptions extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{
    /**
     * @var OptionFactory
     */
    protected $optionFactory;

    /**
     * @param OptionFactory $optionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(OptionFactory $optionFactory)
    {
        $this->optionFactory = $optionFactory;
        //you can use this if you want to prepare options dynamically
        //$coll = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\AttributeSet\Options::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get all options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        /* your Attribute options list*/

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        $coll = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\AttributeSet\Options::class);

        $this->_options=[ ['label'=>'Select Attribute Set', 'value'=>'']];

        foreach($coll->toOptionArray() as $d){
            if($d['label'] !== 'Default') {
                $this->_options[] = ['label' => $d['label'], 'value' => $d['value']];
            }
        }
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($this->_options); die;
        return $this->_options;
    }

    /**
     * Get a text for option value
     *
     * @param string|integer $value
     * @return string|bool
     */
    public function getOptionText($value)
    {
        foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
            if ($option['value'] == $value) {
                return $option['label'];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. My magento version is - 2.1.6 .

Thanks

Comment: Have you created AttributesetOptions.php file? can you please share code?

Comment: Yes...As I mention above, when I am applying "echo "<pre>"; print_r($this->_options); die;"  in that file its printing required array....

Comment: can you please share code?

Comment: I have updated the my question and added "AttributesetOptions.php" files code ....Please check

Comment: Ya it solved- Issue was in Mymodule/CatAttributeSet/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml....
thx @Abdul

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your `AttributesetOptions.php` file

```
<?php
namespace Mymodule\CatAttributeSet\Model\Config\Source;

class AttributesetOptions extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table
{
     /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Convert\DataObject
     */
    protected $_converter;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\CollectionFactory $attrOptionCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\OptionFactory $attrOptionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Convert\DataObject $converter
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\CollectionFactory $attrOptionCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\OptionFactory $attrOptionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Convert\DataObject $converter
    ) {
        $this->_converter = $converter;
        parent::__construct($attrOptionCollectionFactory, $attrOptionFactory);
    }

    /**
     * Get all options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        /* your Attribute options list*/

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $coll = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\AttributeSet\Options::class);
        $this->_options[] = ['value' => ' ', 'label' => __('Select Attribute Set')];  
        foreach($coll->toOptionArray() as $d){
            if($d['label'] !== 'Default') {
                $this->_options[] = ['label' => $d['label'], 'value' => $d['value']];
            }
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }

    /**
     * Get a text for option value
     *
     * @param string|integer $value
     * @return string|bool
     */
    public function getOptionText($value)
    {
        foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
            if ($option['value'] == $value) {
                return $option['label'];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

After run below commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Okay let me try...

Comment: Still same ...., I have updated my question now you can see InstallData.php file full code ...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,`InstallData.php`

```
<?php
namespace Category\Attributes\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'school_name',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'Name',
                'input' => 'select',
                'sort_order' => 333,
                'source' => 'Mymodule\CatAttributeSet\Model\Config\Source\AttributesetOptions',
                'global' => 1,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => null,
                'group' => 'General Information',
                'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend'
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Source model file,

```
Mymodule\CatAttributeSet\Model\Config\Source\AttributesetOptions.php
```

```
namespace Category\Attributes\Model\Category\Attribute\Source;
use Namespace\Modulename\Model\Name;



class Name extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{

    protected $_optionsData;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function __construct($options,CreateFactory $modelCreateFactory)
    {
        $this->_modelCreateFactory = $modelCreateFactory;
        $this->_optionsData = $options;
    }

    /**
     * getAllOptions
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {

        $model = $this->_modelCreateFactory->create();
        $data = $school_model->getCollection()->getData();
        $value1 = array();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $collection = $objectManager->create('Namespace\Modulename\Model\Name');
        $option = $collection->getCollection();
        $optionsArray =[];
        foreach($option as $optionValues) { 
          $optionsArray [] = [
            'label' =>  $optionValues['name'],
            'value' => $optionValues['id']
        ];
        }
        return $optionsArray;
    }
}
```